# MS Team's Tab | How to replace existing client with a React App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, microsoft-graph-api, nodejs-server, msteams-react-base-component

I have created a MS Team's Tab App using https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/tab-sso/nodejs. Currently, the client side is implemented using something called as '.pug' files.

I wanted to use a React App instead. Is there a way, I can achieve this in the same codebase?

Here is the screenshot of the client:
[image]